# How to add reset password functionality in custom module of plugin in admin side?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have created a custom module admin area, in module I have created plugin where I am calling account management class of resources model (which is builin in module-customer) in this class' method Im passing email for reset password, I receives email of reset link but when i click on link url is showing as: mysite.com/admin/customer/resetpassword here I want to remove ony admin with customer but I'm tired can't find it please help me in this regards please
Thanks in advance ☺️

Comment: Could you please add the code you're using to the question? And explain a bit more what's going wrong and what result you expect?

Comment: Suppose I have created module name ab  now I want to send custom email using custom template suppose vustom template  also I have created email is going  but problem is when I add reset email template in my custom email template and when click on reset password from admin it shows your like this  localhost/admin/customer/account/reset-password but I want url should be localhost/customer/account/reset-password.  I will share also code of email template htm and also email trigger function here Thanks 

Comment: <table class="button" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="inner-wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="{{var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword/',[_query:[token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])}}" target="_blank">{{trans "Set a New Password"}}</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

@Gerad  I have above code

Comment: Thx. Could you also please add the code of email_templates.xml where this email template is loaded? This line also has an `area` tag. Possibly `area="adminhtml"` should be changed to `area="frontend"`?

Comment: I have tried both areas adminhtml as well as frontend but still same admin url is coming and im calling this $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend(); and passing name, email, area,storeid

Comment: Can you add the code of the xml file?

Comment: This is xml code in etc: '  <template id="customemail_email_template" label="Custom Reset email" file="customemail.html" type="html" module="CDigital_Impersonation" area="adminhtml"/>'

Comment: I'm trying since last three days even I tried both areas adminhtml as as frontend  but same url

Comment: You also made sure to clear *all* the cache after changing tag to `area="frontend"`?

Comment: Yes also complete deployment but no luck